# Como quitar el encabezado de Apache en Windows

Tags: apache

Actualmente estamos configurando nuestra aplicacion desarrollada con **PHP**, **MySql** y **Apache 2.4.46** sobre **Windows Server2019** uno de los requisitos de seguridad es hacer las cabeceras seguras, para validar esto utilizamos la pagina [Pagina de escaneo de cabeceras](https://securityheaders.com/) y nos arroja la siguiente calificación:
[image: Calificacion del Sitio]
y dentro de los encabezados nos arroja lo siguiente:
[image: Encabezados]

Anteriormente en el encabezado del servidor "Server" nos arrojaba la version de Apache, PHP y hasta de los certificados SSL, dentro del archivo **httpd.conf** se agregaron las lineas **ServerTokens Prod** y **ServerSignature Off** [Documentación Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens) y ahora solo muestra Apache, pero nos comentan que para hacerlo mas seguro es necesario que tampoco muestre esta informacion.

Encontre un articulo acerca de la libreria **ModSecurity** de la pagina [Link de descarga](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/)
Donde agregando:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
 SecRuleEngine on
 ServerTokens Min
 SecServerSignature " "
</IfModule>
```

dentro del archivo http.conf se encarga de ocultarlo, pero al seguir las intrucciones que vienen en el archivo, cuando inicio Apache me manda lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe alguna otra opción?

Comment: ¿Has usado la misma versión de Visual Studio y arquitectura en la descarga del servidor Apache y en el módulo? Deben coincidir ambos, por ejemplo VS16 (Visual Studio C++ 2019) y win64 (64 bits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que hay que hacer es descargar [mod_security2-2.9.3-2.4.x-x](https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx)

Crear el archivo C:\var\log\modsec_audit.log

En **APACHE** copiar los archivos:

- **bin** libcurl.dll, libxml2.dll, pcre.dll, yajl.dll
- **extra** modsecurity-minimal.conf, unicode.mapping
- **modules** mod_security2.so

en el archivo **HTTPD.CONF**, habilitar

- LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so
- Include conf/extra/modsecurity-minimal.conf

y agregar las siguientes lineas:

```
<IfModule security2_module>        
SecRuleEngine On
SecDefaultAction "deny,phase:2,status:403"
ServerTokens Min
SecServerSignature "PATITO" 
</IfModule>
```

donde **PATITO** puede ser cualquier cosa y es lo que aparecera como encabezado, ya sea dejarlo en blanco o escribir un servidor diferente al que realmente se esta utilizando para confundir a los ciber atacantes